# Parabolic p.d.e. with a non-linear second order term

Tags: partial-differential-equations

We are given a parabolic p.d.e of the following general form:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}+\frac{1}{2} f^n \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}=0
$$
Is there a way to transform this p.d.e. to the standard heat equation,
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}+\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2}=0
$$
If not what are the general methods for solving this type of p.d.e.?

Comment: Travelling wave ansatz $f(x,t) = g(z(x,t)) = g(x-ct)$? Then you get $$\frac{-cg'}{g^{2}} + \frac{1}{2} g'' = 0 \implies \frac{c}{g} + \frac{1}{2} g' = K_{1}$$ which shouldn't be too hard to solve. However, this ansatz might not work depending on the boundary and initial conditions.

Comment: Many thanks @mattos that's a very promising approach.